# ChildViewController - enable touch on parent, is it a good pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, containers

I want to divide code into some modules, so I've decided to create 3 `UIViewController`s. One is parent, two other are children. Parent has a view with map etc, both children have custom view with different subviews.

In parent to present child I'm calling:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:controller];
controller.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
[controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

To dismiss a chile I'm using:

```
[controller willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[controller.view removeFromSuperview];
[controller removeFromParentViewController];
```

And everything works great.. besides the fact, that parent view isn't receiving touches. Only children do receive touches. I'd like the parent to have this ability too.

How to **enable touches on parent**..? (ofc userInteractionEnabled is YES but the child's view is stealing a touch)

BTW: **Is this design pattern a good concept** or should I do it somehow else? Other approach with inheritance: `AViewController : UIViewController` (with map), `BViewController : AViewController` and `CViewController : AViewController`- when I change from `BViewController` to `CViewController` I can see the map reload, and I don't want such behaviour.

Comment: You added child 'view to parentViewController as childView.So you can't receive touch, because child overlap the parent.

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft Well in fact I can, when eg I set userInteractionEnabled:NO on child, it passes touches to other views, among others to parent ;). Anyway, I know why it's happening and I'm asking what should be changed or is my design pattern wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've dealt with it following way:

In parent's view:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (hitView == self) {
        return nil;
    }

    return hitView;
}
```

In child's view:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(_myTouchableView.frame, point)) {
        return hitView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean you created two UIView subclasses and assigned them to the viewcontrollers view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you've meant by this question. I had 3 UIViewControllers, each of them had its view assigned (as usual).

Comment: Where do you write the code you showed in the answer?
Since hitTest belongs to UIVIew and not UIViewController

Comment: @user023 In `UIView` subclass, which I swapped in `loadView:` method. I hate storyboards and use MVC, so there is always a `UIView` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Depends for what you need this touch in ParentViewController but i think the best way is to use delegate methods. Simple delegate the touch from the ChildViewController to the ParentViewController.
Basically if you show the ChildViewControllers in the screen you don't need the ParentViewController touches.

Comment: I'm not sure about it. Sending delegates between controllers with touches feels not right. Maybe my design pattern is wrong..? Can I achieve it somehow else without having too much implementation in 1 controller..? I need touches on both parent and child (child is transparent in 80% of places).

Comment: Ok, if you don't want to use delegates methods for this purpose you can use NSNotificationCenter class. See this tutorial http://www.devfright.com/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial/.
Anyway to use this patterns you don't need to write many lines of code.

Comment: I don't mean lines of code. I don't mean that I can't use delegates, notification center, method swizzling or class posing, singletons and many others. I mean that I'm not sure if I chose good pattern, the code quality. Is it fully readable such things will happen and will another developer understand my purpose. I don't think that passing touch is a good idea from the pattern point of view, because noone expects that and these controllers should be independent in such areas. Sending touch is an unexpected behaviour on this class reuse -> so it's wrong in my opinion.

Comment: I think you must to be more clear in your question to have a good answer. When you add the child viewController the parent is still visible?

Comment: I will try to refactor the question, thanks for suggestion. I've bolded the subquestions and changed the title of the question. Yes it is visible, my parent is fullscreen 1 alpha. My child is also fullscreen but only few places have alpha = 1, rest is "visible through" so with 0 alpha.

Comment: Ok, maybe i understood what you want to do. Now, if you have the parentViewController and you add childViewControllers to it, you can't use anymore the parent because he is substituted by the child. In other words it become the container controller like NavigationController or TabBarController that you cant access to it. 
I would do in this way: create a container controller and add to it 3 child viewControllers, than you can have control of each VC and touches of course.

Comment: That approach would be good, but my parent has fullscreen map, and child have visible subviews in corners. If I do as you say, my map won't be fullscreen.

Comment: You can do in many ways this work, even creating custom UIView instead of UIViewController. Hope you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `UIView`'s method `pointInside:withEvent`. You can pass a touch event through a view to its `superView` as you want. Simply indicate which rect is "transparent to touch" and return `NO`.